# For a process $A_t$, does $|| \mathbb{E}[A_{t+1}] ||_\infty \leq \delta ||A_t||_\infty$ imply that $A_t \to 0$?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, convergence-divergence, stochastic-processes, random-variables

I'm currently studying some stochastic approximation-like algorithms and their convergence properties. I'm wondering whether some convergence results from deterministic sequences can be transferred to random-processes.

Consider a (non-random) sequence $(a_t)_t$ which satifies, for constant $\delta \in (0, 1)$:

$$|a_{t+1}| \leq \delta |a_t| \ \forall t$$

Then, $a_t \rightarrow 0$.

Now consider a random process $(A_t)_t$ with:

$$|| \mathbb{E}[A_{t+1}] ||_\infty \leq \delta ||A_t||_\infty$$

Does $A_t \rightarrow 0$ as well? Or are there other requierements that have to be fullfilled?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is the index set of the proccess? $\Bbb{N}$ or $\Bbb{R}$? Also, just knowing something about the expected value will not help much. For example, your assumption is *always* satisfied if $\Bbb{E}[A_t] = 0$ for all $t$, but not every such process converges to zero.

Comment: It is $\mathbb{N}$. Thanks for the counterexample!

Comment: Please avoid "do my homework for me"-style questions. For example, simply telling us where you got the problem from or explaining what you tried would be a big step forward! (For further feedback/help with asking questions, you can ask [here](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/43593/constructive-feedback).)

Comment: @user1729 I can't understand why this is a "do my homework for me"-style question. Especially if one considers, that there is no known existing answer to it, so it must be a really sadistic professor.

Comment: @user1729 I made it, the problem, up myself.

Comment: The point is that you should always explain the context. If you made it up yourself, include that information in the post and add in which context/why you did that. What is your motivation. It does not have to be something deep. Just explain a bit how it came about.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@PhoemueX gave a counterexample in the comments that showed that this doesn't hold in general.

You asked for other requirements for this to be true. Below is one example of a situation where your assertion holds.

First, since we're talking random variables, we have more than one type of convergence. I'm assuming $A_t \to 0$ means $A_t {\to} 0\; almost\; surely\;(a.s)$.

**Assumption 1** $A_t:\Omega \to \mathbb{R^+}$

This allows your condition to be simplified:

$$||E[A_{t+1}]||_{\infty} \leq \delta ||A_t||_{\infty} \implies E[A_{t+1}] \leq \delta A_t$$

Now, note that $E[A_{t+1}]$ is bounded by a random variable, so unless $E[A_t] = 0\;\;\forall t$ we need to assume something about the conditional expectation $E[A_{t+1}|A_t]$. Let's assume that it also follows your bound

**Assumption 2**: $E[A_{t+1}|A_t] \leq \delta A_t$

**Assumptions 1 and 2** imply that $A_t$ is a [supermartingale](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Martingale_(probability_theory)#Submartingales,_supermartingales,_and_relationship_to_harmonic_functions) bounded from below.

This allows us to apply [Doob's Supermartingale Convergence Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doob%27s_martingale_convergence_theorems):

$$\sup E[A_t^-] =0<\infty \implies \lim_{t\to\infty}A_t(\omega) = A(\omega)<\infty\;\; a.s.$$

$$ \textrm{Where}\; A_t^- = \max(-A_t,0)$$

Therefore, we've shown that $\lim_{t\to\infty}A_t$ is finite and exists $a.s.$

Now, we need to show $A(\omega) = 0\;a.s.$

We can take advantage of our conditional expectation formulation to show that the *expected value* of $A_t$ converges to $0$:

$$E[A_{t+1}|A_t] \leq \delta A_t \implies E[E[A_{t+1}|A_t]] \leq E[\delta A_t]=\delta E[A_t]$$

Since $E[E[X|Y]] = E[X]$ (see [law of total expectation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_expectation)) we have the deterministic sequence:

$$E[E[A_{t+1}|A_t]] = E[A_{t+1}] \leq \delta E[A_t]$$

From here we can get:

$$E[A_t] = \delta^t E[X_0] \implies \lim_{t\to\infty} E[A_t] = 0$$

However, convergence in mean doesn't imply convergence $a.s.$ To get to that, we need to use [Markov's Inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markov%27s_inequality):

$$X\geq 0 \implies P(X\geq a)\leq \frac{E[X]}{a}\;\;\forall a > 0$$

Applying this to our case, we have:

$$A_t \geq 0 \implies P(A_t \geq a) \leq \frac{E[A_t]}{a} = \frac{\delta^t E[X_0]}{a}\;\forall a > 0$$

Since we've shown that $E[A_t] \to 0$ we can conclude that $A_t \to 0\; a.s.$

$$\lim_{t\to\infty} P(A_t\geq a) = 0 \;\;\forall a>0$$

Since this holds for any $a>0$, we can conclude that $A_t$ converges to the degenerate random variable $A=0$ almost surely.

Comment: Hello @Bey, cool answer, but I don't get the beginning argument of how 
$$\|E[A_{t+1}]\|_\infty \leq \delta \|A_{t}\|_\infty \implies E[A_{t+1}] \leq \delta A_{t}\implies E[A_{t+1}|A_t] \leq \delta A_{t} $$
Could you get more into detail?

Comment: @Snoop the uniform norm of a nonnegative scaler $x$ is just $x$ https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_norm

Comment: That's clear for $E[A_{t+1}] $, I'm referring to the rest

Comment: @Snoop the expectation of $A_{t+1}$ is bounded from above by a random variable hence it is a function of a random variable which makes it a conditional expectation given a random variable https://www.stat.auckland.ac.nz/~fewster/325/notes/ch3.pdf

Comment: Since $A_t$ is a function and $\|A_t\|_\infty=\inf\{C\geq 0:|A_t|\leq C\,  a.s.\}$ why does $E[A_{t+1}]\leq \delta A_t$ follow from $E[A_{t+1}]\leq \delta \|A_t\|_\infty$?

Comment: The auckland reference does not contain suitable info, but I get the intuition

Comment: @Snoop correct — the Auckland reference was solely to explain the move to conditional expectation not the infinity norm part.

Comment: The property $E[A_{t+1}]\leq (1/2)A_t$ does not imply $E[A_{t+1}|A_t]\leq (1/2)A_t$. Take $A_1 \in \{1, 2\}$ equally likely, let $$A_2 = \left\{\begin{array}{cc} 1 & \mbox{if $A_1=1$}\\ 0 & \mbox{else} \end{array}\right.$$

Comment: @Michael ah, now I see what Snoop was concerned with! My idea was to show that $E[A_{t+1}$ is a random variable bounded by $A_t$. Specifically, if you set $E[A-{t+1]=\delta A_t} and then carry the logic forward. My mistake was that I cannot say that for any generic conditional expectation (as you pointed out) but only if I define a process that has that characteristic. So, looks like I need to add another condition in my demonstration.

Comment: @Michael I've updated my proof to to make the supermartingale assumption clear

Comment: @Bey : Makes sense +1

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer!! So for a multi-dimensional random process $X_t \in \mathbb{R}^n$ one could state that if $\mathbb{E}[||X_{t+1}||_\infty] \leq \delta ||X_t||_\infty$ and $\mathbb{E}[||X_{t+1}||_\infty| \ ||X_t||_\infty] \leq \delta ||X_t||_\infty$, then $X_t \rightarrow 0 \in \mathbb{R^n}$ almost surely (Which can be proven by applying your prove for $A_t := ||X_t||_\infty$)

Comment: @NickHalden that sounds right...I didn't try to tackle the broader case but I figured there might be similar reasoning for $X_t \in \mathbb{R}^n$